# How do I remove the underline in a list?

Tags: html, css

when i make a list and insert an image in front of it (in my case a normal checkbox). then an underline appears under this checkbox.
I tried to remove it as follows:
text-decoration: none;
but it did not help. what should I do?

```css
    .galka1 {
        padding: 10px 8px 0px 0px;
        text-decoration-line: none;
    }

    .text6 {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 36px;
        color: #273d46;
        font-family: "Arial";
        filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
    }

  

    .spisok {
    width: 852px;
    height: 279px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #273d46;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="spisok">
         <li class="text6"><img src="galka.png" class="galka1" />Put on this page information aboutyour product</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Did you use `text-decoration: none` on `ul.spisok`?

Comment: yes i did it. I edited the question and now you can see my .spisok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underline is actually due to Filter drop-shadow.

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6));
```

Increases the blur amount to make it like a shadow. Like,

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/jOMvPap

#### The better way to do so is to add `box-shadow` to the `img`.

Like:

```
box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/GRjXJdE

Comment: thanks a lot! I just remove "filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);  " from ever and it shows with out underline!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You added a shadow to .spisok that adds a small shadow line:

```
.spisok {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
}
```

And also you make that shadow line bigger here:

```
.text6 {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
}
```

If you remove that shadow in both classes the underline will be removed.